# Convert MySQL query to Python

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to write a `SELECT` query with a `WHERE` condition and `ORDER BY`.

I have the query in `MySQL` and would like to convert it to `Python`.

This is my `Mysql`-Query:

```
SELECT StoreId
     , ProductCode
     , TotalQuantity
FROM storeinvoicedetails
WHERE StoreId=1
ORDER BY ProductCode
```

This is what I tried in `Python`:

```
sql = "SELECT StoreId,ProductCode,TotalQuantity FROM storeinvoicedetails  \
       WHERE StoreId = '%d'" % (1) \
       "ORDER BY '%s' '%s'" % ('ProductCode','ASC')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   query =  """SELECT StoreId,ProductCode,TotalQuantity FROM storeinvoicedetails WHERE StoreId={0} ORDER BY ProductCode ASC""".format(store_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> sql = "SELECT StoreId,ProductCode,TotalQuantity FROM storeinvoicedetails  \
   WHERE StoreId = '%d' \
   ORDER BY ProductCode ASC" % id
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
STOREID = 1
# make sure you add the last space for every line, otherwise it will look like 'TotalQuantityFROM' causing an error
myQuery = "SELECT StoreId,ProductCode,TotalQuantity " + 
          "FROM storeinvoicedetails " +
          "WHERE StoreId=" + str(STOREID) + " "
          "ORDER BY ProductCode"
```